# AWS Amplify / Dynamo - array of objects coming back as array of strings

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify, react-select

I'm using `react-select` as a 'multi-select' in a react-app to set multiple music genres. This results in an array of objects as the value for that input. I'm using AWS Amplify / DynamoDB.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my schema.graphql (below), how I'm handling / mishandling the data, or just my general coding deficits, but the data gets sent like this:

```
[{label='Afrobeat', value='Afrobeat'}, {label='Bikutsi', value='Bikutsi'}, {label='Benga', value='Benga'}]
```

And returns like this (single quotes stripped), double quotes added around each node):

```
["{label=Afrobeat, value=Afrobeat}", "{label=Bikutsi, value=Bikutsi}", "{label=Benga, value=Benga}"]
```

`react-select` can't process the data like that but I can't imagine I would have to do some tricky client-side handling to make it work. Any help would be graciously appreciated.

My **schema.graphql** for this Song type is:

```
type Song @model {
  album: Album @connection(name: "AlbumSongs")
  composer: String
  description: String
  duration: String
  genre: [String!]! // is this the correct value for an array?
  id: ID!
  instruments: String
  tags: [String!]!
  title: String!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to have another type `GenreOptions` to make it return as an array of objects instead of array of strings.

Something like:

```
type GenreOptions {
  label: String!
  value: String! // also another option is to have an enum type
}

type Song @model {
  genre: [GenreOptions!]!
}
```

Then the query would look like:

```
Song {
  genre {
    label
    value
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. I have over a thousand genres... how would I 'enum' those in the GenreValues object? (presently I'm just pulling them from a `data.js` file in my app).

Comment: No problem. Another alternative for enum is just `value: String!`.

Comment: Awesome. So to be clear, like this: `enum GenreValues { value: String! }`? (SV Code is coloring it weird so I'm wondering if I have it right).

Comment: @KirkRoss I've updated the code. No need for enum if you'll be using string.

Comment: Gigathanks. BTW... trivia... if you happen to have watched, Silicon Valley my brother plays Gavin Belson on it :)